# Use CRAN without setting a mirror

Tags: cran

I am trying to knit a report template to produce an html doc but I get the following error:
|...................................                 |  67% [unnamed-chunk-1]

processing file: ReportTemplate-1.Rmd

Quitting from lines 65-115 [unnamed-chunk-1] (ReportTemplate-1.Rmd)

Error in `contrib.url()`:
! trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Backtrace:

1. utils::install.packages("tidyverse")
2. utils::contrib.url(repos, "source")
   Execution halted

I am trying to knit a report template and was expecting to receive an html doc